# iOS UIActionSheet as a plugin

Tags: ios, uialertview, uiactionsheet, appirater

I have a question about UIActionSheet. I'd like to create a little iOS plugin. Something like Appirater except instead of showing UIAlertView I'd like to show UIActionSheet with some customized options.

Nevertheless I don't know to what kind of app the plugin will be attached to? So basically under my ActionSheet could be anything. In UIAlertView you just call `[myAlert show]` and it works. Here you've got to call `[myActionSheet showInView:myView]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin isn't the right term. You mean library or possibly framework. Anyway, assuming you are asking about the API you would provide in the main class of your library, you have a few options. You could provide a set of methods that essentially mirror the various 'show' methods of UIActionSheet and let the client of your library call the appropriate one. Or you could make it simpler and just make the client provide a view controller. Your library can then look at the view controller and show the action sheet appropriately. If the view controller is in a tabbed view, you show the action sheet that way. If the view controller has a toolbar, you show the action sheet for the toolbar. If all else fails, you show the action sheet from the view controller's view.

But either way, your API needs to get at least something from the client so it can properly show the action sheet.

Comment: Oh that's disappointing :) So I couldn't f.e. create my customized view which shows that ActionSheet and somehow put it on the screen like UIAlertView? Without any client information or having client call my function?

Comment: Actually, with a bit more thought, you can probably walk through some combination of the responder chain or window view hierarchy to find the top most view controller yourself. Start with the main window root view controller. You'll have to look for tab controllers, nav controllers, etc. then look for presented view controllers. Or start by finding the current first responder and determine its view controller. It's doable but you need to be careful to cover every possible case. Once you determine that topmost view controller you can do what I said before.